# How to replace texts inside matching elements via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">10,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
```

I want when if point is `10,0`, remove `,0`.:

```
 <span class="point">10</span>
```

I was put alert with length but its not working.

```
    $('.point').each(function () {
        if ($('.point').text().length > 4) {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
```

It was all points get alert.

What's my problem? How can I solve it?

---

### Snippet

```js
$('.point').each(function () {
  if ($('.point').text().length > 4) {
    alert("ok");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">10,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
```

Comment: `if ($('.point').text().length > 4) {` should be `if ($(this).text().length > 4) {`

Comment: Also `>= 4` or `> 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if just for 10 then...

```js
$('.point').each(function () {
     var textAfterComma = $(this).text().split(",");
     if (textAfterComma[0] === '10' && textAfterComma[1] === '0') {
         $(this).text(textAfterComma[0]);
     }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">10,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc6jmtt2/1/

if you want all numbers ending with ,0 to be just the first number then...

```js
$('.point').each(function () {
     var textAfterComma = $(this).text().split(",");
     if (textAfterComma[1] === '0') {
         $(this).text(textAfterComma[0]);
     }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">10,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc6jmtt2/

For you example at the bottom of your question there are two fixes:

First `$('.point')` to `$(this)` then `if ($(this).text().length > 4) {` to `if ($(this).text().length >= 4) {` or `> 3` because none of your strings are `> 4`

```
$('.point').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().length >= 4) {
    alert("ok");
  }
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc6jmtt2/3/

Answer (score 1):

Because `$('.point').text()` is the concatenation of the text in **all** elements with class `.point`, you should use `$(this).text()`.

Also, you condition should be `>=4` or `==== "10,0`

### Here's a better way:

```js
$('.point:contains("10,0")').text('10');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">10,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).text()` instead. Using `$(".point").text()` results in concatenation of all text of point class like: `8,0 8,0 10,0 8,0`
So:

```js
$('.point').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().length > 3) {
    alert("OK");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
<span class="point">10,0</span>
<span class="point">8,0</span>
```

Comment: Why even post an answer that just mimics the other answers?

Comment: Sorry, I started typing it before the other one was posted and only realized after submitting my answer. Should I delete it then? (I joined just recently and hence not very familiar with all the workings)

Comment: No, just 15 minutes after our answers you posted.  Seemed like you were just trying to copy an answer.